# Connecting to Aurora Serverless via intra-region VPC Peering

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, amazon-aurora, vpc

I have two AWS accounts, which I will call `prod` and `dev`.

`prod` has an Aurora Serverless cluster (not instance!), perfectly connectable within its own VPC in the `prod` account. To save time and money, I would like to use this cluster in `dev` (obviously with read-only permissions, etc) instead of spinning up a new cluster, mostly due to volume of data and the need for parity during development.

I have set up `dev` exactly the same as `prod`, minus the Aurora cluster and with a different CIDR block for the VPC. I have set up a VPC peering connection between the VPCs in `dev` and `prod` with DNS resolution on both VPCs and enabled in the peering connection. I have added this peering connection to the route tables for each VPC, with the affected subnets explicitly associated. I have added both CIDR and SGs (including the VPC default SG, as I read recommended on SO in a tangentially related answer) to all affected SGs (Aurora cluster SG, SG for Lambda that is calling out to Aurora, default SG for VPC in both accounts). I also added the CIDR blocks to the ACL explicitly.

I can't get any kind of connection whatsoever. Documentation on whether this is even possible leads me in a recursive loop of not-quite-useful information, though it does seem the intra-region peering should be possible. I am no network expert, so it's entirely possible I have just horribly misconfigured something along the way, but I can't find any guides or useful documentation for this particular situation.

Is this even possible? Is there a checklist somewhere of changes to be made to allow connections like this (outside of the severely lacking AWS docs on VPC peering)? Route tables, subnets, security groups, ACLs, VPC peering connections...it's a lot of pieces and I feel like at this point I have just missed something, despite having torn down/reconfigured this setup via several guides.

Comment: Aurora Serverless uses some hidden network magic to allow it to (among other things) accept connections when it isn't actually running, start up, and handle those connections.  Reading between the lines, within a region across a VPC peering connection, this may only currently work when you are using an instance with a [Nitro hypervisor](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html#ec2-nitro-instances) -- like c5, m5, r5, and t3.  Peering involves the hypervisors (it's not an actual gateway) so older instance types can't necessarily do everything newer ones can.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot excuse I'm not 100% sure I follow what you're suggesting, so excuse me if this is incredibly wrong: I will need to create an EC2 with Nitro (in `prod`?) that would effectively tunnel my connection through to the VPCE for Aurora? Currently I have a non-Nitro instance setup as a Bastion host that allows connections to the Aurora from outside via SSH tunneling without these issues, so I'm not 100% how or where the Nitro EC2 would work/allow those connections. Appreciate the help!

Comment: If I'm right, the only instances in VPC B that can access Aurora Serverless in VPC A (via intra-region peering) would be Nitro instances.  You could use any kind of machine as a proxy in the same VPC as Aurora or a Nitro-based machine as a proxy in the remote VPC.  Simple test, fire up a t3 in the foreign VPC and see if it can access the serverless cluster.

Comment: Amazon has answered this for me with the newly announced [VPC sharing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-sharing.html)